# How to replace first occurrence only in vim

Tags: vim, vi, greedy, regex-greedy, boost-regex

Is there any option to replace the first occurrence without asking for confirmation in vim?

I want to replace New York with `\place{New York}` in the first occurrence only without asking for confirmation. I used this code:

```
silent! /\\begin{text}/,/\\end{textit}/s/New York/\\place{New York}/g

> \begin{text}..[paragraphs]...\end{textit}
```

`New York` may be contained 10 times in the paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to in a line range do only single substitution, not one sub per line. So the `/start/,/end/ s/pat/rep/` will not work. I would make your example simpler, given that we have:

```
foo
nyc nyc
nyc nyc
bar
```

I guess what you are expecting to have is

```
foo
\\place{nyc} nyc
nyc nyc
bar
```

However `:/foo/,/bar/ s/nyc/\\place{&}` will give

```
foo
\\place{nyc} nyc
\\place{nyc} nyc
bar
```

Because `:s` will do sub for each line in range.

I would narrow the range to solve this problem:

```
/foo//nyc/s/nyc/\\place{&}/
```

note that between `/foo/ and /nyc/`, there is no comma.

The output should be:

```
foo
\\place{nyc} nyc
nyc nyc
bar
```

You may want to read `:h range` for details.

Answer (score 2):

The `/g` flag at the end of your substitution means that it will be performed on *every* occurence of your search pattern. Remove it and it will only be performed on the first occurence.

Also, `:s` doesn't ask for confirmation by default; you would need to add the `/c` flag for that. So I'm not sure why you prepend it with `:silent`.

Another comment: You can reuse the matched text in the replace part with `&`:

```
:/\\begin{text}/,/\\end{textit}/s/New York/\\place{&}
```

Comment: if a pattern is not found then, it show some error msg ,like pattern not found, if we use silent!, then it will not show the err msgs.

Comment: Those messages are useful.

Comment: but i have lot of search patterns in my function, may be 300. so the message shown each time, will made me disturbed.